# JQuery - Swapping Order Of Content On Resize

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where I want so swap the content of some divs at a certain breakpoint so that the text always appears above the image.

Please see codepen link below:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpOvGq?editors=1010

The jquery that is doing this is below:

```
$(window).on('load',reorderOnCollapse);
$(window).on('resize',reorderOnCollapse);

function reorderOnCollapse() {

    if($('#collapse').css('display') == 'none') {

        $(".container:nth-child(even)").css("border","10px solid red");
        $(".container:nth-child(even) .image").insertAfter(".container:nth-child(even) .text");

    } else {

        $(".container:nth-child(even)").css("border","10px solid orange");  
        $(".container:nth-child(even) .text").insertAfter(".container:nth-child(even) .image");

    }

}
```

For some reason this is generating extra copies of content.

I think it's because I'm not telling it do it on an individual element but apply to all elements of that type.

How do I specify to do it once per element as opposed to for all?

Thanks for your time and help with this.

Comment: Please describe schematically what you are trying to achieve, but when you say breakpoint you should consider a css alternative using media queries.

Comment: CSS media queries are being used.  The jquery looks for a div which is either set to 'block' or 'none'.  Please look at the CSS in the CodePen link.